# Adding Directory Structure To SVN Repo

Tags: svn

I've never administered an svn repository before, although I have used svn for version control.  I set up an svn repository on a RHEL 5 server using the following tutorial: http://mark.koli.ch/2010/03/howto-setting-up-your-own-svn-server-using-apache-and-mod-dav-svn.html

Everything is working smoothly as it, but my repository doesn't have the tradition trunk/branch/tags structure.  I set up a new repository, and used mkdir to add "tags", "trunk", and "branches" folders, and then tried checking out a working copy on another machine.  It checks out at revision 0, but without the directory structure.  I'm guessing that simply adding those folders isn't enough.

Can someone please explain what I would need to do so that when I check out a working copy I get the whole directory structure?

FOLLOW UP QUESTION
Thanks to everyone who chimed in.  I created two test repositories to play with, and now wish to delete them.  Is it really just as simple as removing the folders from the server?  I googled "svnadmin remove repo" and I get info on using the svn remove command, but that's to remove a file from a repository.  I want to completely remove a repository.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One missing step in your story is the point when you [commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html) your tags/trunk/branches 
directories, did you do the commit ?

e.g.

```
svn co http://my_repo/ .

mkdir tags
mkdir trunk
mkdir branches

svn add tags
svn add trunk
svn add branches

svn ci . -m "definitely add those directories to the repository"
```

Comment: @Cedric:  perfecto!  Yes, I was missing this step.  I understand the concepts of checking out and checking in, but didn't realize that I could make the directory structure in the working directory and commit back the repo.

Comment: @Alvaro:  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: How can I do the same if I don't want to first check out the entire repo? How can I add a folder structure to the root of a repository that is many gigabytes large?

Comment: shouldn´t one also move the files inside trunk ? otherwise - what is the point of having these folders ?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't feel like committing and want to automate it:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repo
svn mkdir file:///path/to/repo/trunk
svn mkdir file:///path/to/repo/tags
svn mkdir file:///path/to/repo/branches
```